# Jquery load() from which directory?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm learning to use CodeIgniter.

In one of the view file, lets say `someview.php`, I'm trying to run another php file `toload.php` from a Jquery when `someview.php` is done loading:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">                                       
      $(document).ready( function() { 
           $('#load_something').load('toload.php'); 
      }); 
  </script>
```

My question is, where does the function `load()` try to load from?
Is it from `www.mysite.com/toload.php`? or from the same directory as the `someview.php` file? or from the root directory of public_html?

I read the docs for `load()` and checked some tutorials, but I'm still unsure about the actual folder structure.

Comment: The root directory is the current directory as shown in the URL. The easiest way to get around path depth issues is to always base your paths from the root, eg. `/toload.php`

Comment: Think of it exactly the same as an `href` in an `<a>`. The browser bases relative links starting at current path in address bar if no `/` or `../` preceding url you provide

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same as if you provided a URL in, say, an `<a>` tag. It's relative to the current directory. You can always provide an absolute URL, for example `/pages/toload.php` if you can't be sure where the file will be located.